# Co-Clustering using python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I need to do Co-clustering analysis for a dataset that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cell 1': [(2, 5), (27, 5), (3, 3), (2, 3)],
                   'Cell 2': [(26, 3), (23, 31), (21, 30), (1, 3)],
                   'Cell 3': [(2, 30), (12, 3), (25, 36), (42, 3)],
                   'Cell 4': [(11, 13), (5, 3), (20, 30), (6, 21)]},
                  index=['Drug 1', 'Drug 2', 'Drug 3', 'Drug 4'])
```

each node consists of a tuples that contains two values. Anyone knows how to do Bi-clustering analysis for such dataset in python?
** of course the actual dataset is much bigger than this one

Comment: you can use one of ML modules like skilearn

Comment: thank you @eshirvana for the comment. I did see some of skilearn demos but I found them hard to understand. I was wondering if someone could share his own code with some explanations  :)